# How to be able to remove event listener while maintaining access to 'this'?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to setup a 'global save' button that will invoke an event in any class that has a save button by using event listeners.

If I add an event listener to my event with a reference to the save method in that particular class then I don't have access to that class instance anymore so I can't save the data.

If I add an event listener to my event with an arrow function then I have access to the instance but I'm unable to close that event if needed later.

How could I either access the instance when passing a reference or remove the listener when using the arrow function?

I've tried to use .bind when passing a reference to the method with 'this' as the parameter but not only was I unable to access the instance that way but I was also unable to remove the listener.

Pieces of code when using reference (no access to 'this'):

```
document.addEventListener('save-all', this.test, false);

document.removeEventListener('save-all', this.test, false);
```

Pieces of code when using arrow function (unable to remove listener):

```
document.addEventListener('save-all', e => this.test(), false);

document.removeEventListener('save-all', this.test, false);
document.removeEventListener('save-all', e => this.test(), false);
```

Function itself (name is a ko observable in that class):

```
public test(): void
{
    console.log(this.name());
}
```

Comment: `const handler = e => this.test();` then add or remove `handler`.

Comment: @zerkms ahhh, thank you. post that as a solution and i'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in a variable then use for both attaching and removing

```
const handler = e => this.test();

document.addEventListener('save-all', handler, false);

document.removeEventListener('save-all', handler, false);
```