# createjs off() function to remove listener from js arrow function

Tags: javascript, createjs, arrow-functions

I use the on() function of createjs:

```
myObj.on("mousedown", (e)=>{
    this.myObjMouseDown(e);
});
```

now, I want to remove the listener, I trying to write this code, with the off() function:

```
myObj.off("mousedown", (e)=>{
    this.myObjMouseDown(e);
});
```

but, The code does not seem to be working correctly.

How should I write to cancel the event?

Note: Notice that I need to use an arrow function, because of the word "this".

Comment: Does createjs provide the `on`/`off` event handler methods? Or are you also loading in jQuery?

Comment: no jQuery. only createjs and zimjs. the on() is method of createjs.

Comment: You can also just use the 3rd parameter (scope) if you don't want to use an arrow function. `obj.on("click", fn, this);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594241/how-to-be-able-to-remove-event-listener-while-maintaining-access-to-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the same function -- but it is important to note that the `on` method creates a wrapper function for you no matter what, since it also allows you to do pass a scope parameter. The `on/off` methods were made specifically to address the issue of scope in ES5. ([docs](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on))

The best way to make sure you can unsubscribe is to store a reference to the value of the `on` function call, and pass that to `off()`.

```
var evt = obj.on("click", () => doSomething());
// later
obj.off("click", evt);
```

Another great way to cancel events is to remove them in the function callback:

```
doSomething(evt) {
    // Your Code
    if (condition) {
        evt.remove();
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you are just looking for a clean-up, use `removeAllEventListeners` ([docs](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_removeAllEventListeners)), which you can pass an optional event type to.

```
obj.removeAllEventListeners("click");
```

Comment: In this case, obj.removeAllEventListeners("mousedown"); - did the work! Thanks @Lanny!